# After upgrading flutter version from v1.12.13+hotfix.8 to 1.17.0 getting such error

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

Compiler message:
../../../Public/FlutterSDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_cupertino_date_picker-1.0.12/lib/src/date_picker_theme.dart:39:9: Error: The superclass, 'Diagnosticable', has no unnamed constructor that takes no arguments.
  const DateTimePickerTheme({
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception: Errors during snapshot creation: null
build failed.

Comment: can you try this: https://github.com/Realank/flutter_datetime_picker/issues/128#issuecomment-609597517

Answer (score 0):

**If you are using flutter_cupertino_date_picker, you may be will need to update it, This is working with me:**

```
flutter_cupertino_date_picker: ^1.0.26
```